# Best way to cache map tiles in an Angular 8 project with Leaflet

Tags: angular, caching, leaflet

I'm working on an Angular project (v8.2.1) that uses Leaflet (v1.3.4). Now I would like to add **tile caching**, but all the libraries I've found so far are either unusable because they're not compatible with Angular, or haven't been maintained in over a year: e.g.
  https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached
  https://github.com/yagajs/leaflet-cached-tile-layer

My request is: can anybody who has experience with this sort of thing give me a recommendation? I'm looking for something compatible with current technologies.

Comment: The only long-term solution is to become a maintainer of such caching libraries and pledge to offer long-term support.

Comment: Good point. I've edited my question. Thank you for all your work on Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached @IvanSanchez - now if it had been compatible with my Angular project I would have used that.